# Unable to Enqueue Scripts in Child Theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm attempting to register and enqueue a script from a javascript file in a child theme. The script appears to register just fine, returning true, however nothing happens when the script is enqueued. Are there any problems with the way I am registering or enqueueing?

In functions.php, I'm checking the user's role, and registering and enqueuing scripts from custom_functions.js if that user has the role of 'ad_greensboro'.

```
function tutor_portal_scripts() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array( 'ad_greensboro', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        debug_to_console("User is AD Greensboro");
        wp_register_script('set_rollup_links_greensboro', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_functions.js', array(jquery), '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('set_rollup_links_greensboro');
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tutor_portal_scripts' );
```

Below is the entire contents of my custom JS file. Its purpose is to change the href property for three links on a specific page.

```js
function set_rollup_links_greensboro() {
 console.log("Set rollup links for Greensboro AD");
 
 var at_link = document.getElementById('at-view-link');
 var bas_link = document.getElementById('bas-view-link');
 var tutor_link = document.getElementById('tutors-view-link');

  at_link.setAttribute('href', 'https://devts.techstartutors.com/appointment-tracker-form-view-greensboro-nc/');
  bas_link.setAttribute('href', 'https://devts.techstartutors.com/book-a-service-form-view-greensboro-nc/');
  tutor_link.setAttribute('href', 'https://devts.techstartutors.com/');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `error_log( in_array( 'ad_greensboro', (array) $user->roles ) );` return? (make sure you have [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled first)

Comment: `array(jquery)` is a typo, hopefully not in your code.  Must be `array("jquery")` or `array('jquery')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript file, you should call that function. So add the following code to the end of your javascript file:

`set_rollup_links_greensboro();`

Comment: Doing that executes set_rollup_links_greensboro() every time. I want to have it run on the condition that the current user has a certain role ("ad_greensboro").

Comment: @EvanScott - not according to your `enqueue` code (the PHP code).  That script is _only_ included when the user is the right role, correct? So - this answer is correct,

Comment: My apologies! That's correct. Thank you for the help.